Difficulty Accessing SQLite Tables in Django Environment
My Testing Environment:

Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 22H2
Anaconda Version: 24.1.2 (Python 3.11.7)
Integrated Development Environment: Visual Studio Code 1.89.1
Django Version: 5.0.6

Problem:
I'm new to Django and currently exploring its documentation. I successfully completed the first section, Writing your first Django app, part 1 (How to setting up your first App) as per the instructions provided. However, I'm encountering difficulties understanding the second section, Writing your first Django app, part 2 (How to work with databases) particularly in working with databases.
The documentation mentions that SQLite is the default database and should be accessible without additional installation, which aligns with my understanding. Following the instructions, I ran the command python manage.py migrate without any issues.
However, when attempting to show the created tables using the SQLite command .tables, I encountered the following error:
(.venv) PS C:\Users\marco\Desktop\DjangoProject\EuroChampBettingSite> .tables
.tables : The term '.tables' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .tables
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.tables:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Additionally, trying to check the SQLite version using sqlite --version yielded another error:
(.venv) PS C:\Users\marco\Desktop\DjangoProject\EuroChampBettingSite> sqlite --version
sqlite : The term 'sqlite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sqlite --version
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sqlite:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Question:
It appears that SQLite is not recognized or properly installed in my environment, contrary to what the documentation suggests. Could anyone clarify if SQLite is indeed included with Django installations, and if so, how can I troubleshoot and rectify this issue? Any guidance on resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not 100% sure on Windows, so I can't help you with installing SQLite on your machine, however Django provides a better solution.
You can run this command python manage.py dbshell and you're connected to your SQLite database :)
